# Android development: Check if WebView is Scrolled to Right Or Left

Tags: android, webview, gesture, swipe

Im using GestureListner to Swipe against Tab(TabHost) But in one tab there is a WebView. And if the WebView is zoomed in and the user fling it switch tab and I don't want that! :)

Ive tried `if(!web.zoomoOut())` and it works half it checks if cant zoomed out but it also zooms out. So that won't work

So is there anyway to check if webview is all zoomed out or if Horizontal Scrollbar == 0 or Horizontal Scrollbar == SCROLL_MAX?

//Simon

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `webview.getScale()` method